# C++ Class using header and implemenation files

Tags: c++

I've put together a simple C++ "Hello World" program to practice; unfortunately, upon compilation I get a few errors:

> expected ')' before fName
>
> error: prototype for 'HelloWorld::HelloWorld(std::string, std::string)' does not match any in class 'HelloWorld'

Below is my code, can anyone help me understand what I'm missing/overlooking? Thanks.

**Header:**

```
  1 #ifndef HELLOWORLD_H_ 
  2 #define HELLOWORLD_H_
  3 #include <string>
  4 
  5 class HelloWorld
  6 {
  7     public:
  8         HelloWorld();
  9         HelloWorld(string fName, string lName);
 10         ~HelloWorld();
 11 };
 12 
 13 #endif
```

**Implementation:**

```
  1 #include <iostream>
  2 #include <string>
  3 #include "HelloWorld.h"
  4 
  5 using namespace std;
  6 
  7 HelloWorld::HelloWorld()
  8 {
  9     cout << "Hello, anonymous!";
 10 }
 11 
 12 HelloWorld::HelloWorld(string fName, string lName)
 13 {
 14     cout << "Hello, " << fName << ' ' << lName << endl;
 15 }
 16 
 17 HelloWorld::~HelloWorld()
 18 {
 19     cout << "Goodbye..." << endl;
 20 }
```

Comment: Please don't use line numbers in code posted here, particularly if you don't refer to them in your question. They make it hard to copy and paste the code into a file for compilation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to change your header file to reference `std::string` instead of `string` because they are defined inside the std namespace.

```
HelloWorld(std::string fName, std::string lName);
```

It works in your .cpp file because you specifically import this namespace.  The solution however is not to import this namespace in your header file (generally speaking a bad idea in C++).

Comment: If you must, you can import individual names, like `using std::string`.  I'd still be reluctant, but it doesn't defeat the whole purpose of using a namespace.

Comment: Are there any situations were importing namespaces into the header file is advisable?

Comment: even `using std::string` isnt such a good idea its always better to use std::string in the declarations in header files

Answer (score 3):

If the code is exactly like what you pasted into the question, the most probable cause of the error is that in the header, the compiler is not identifying what `string` means, as it is not a symbol in the global namespace. Try fully qualifying it:

```
class HelloWorld
{
//...
   HelloWorld( std::string fName, std::string lName );
};
```